# How do you represent this statement in first order number logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm a little confused as to where to begin in translating this to first order number logic:

$y = \lfloor\sqrt[3]{x}\rfloor$ where $U = \Bbb{Z}$

Not really looking for an answer, just some help with getting started.

Comment: You want to say that $y\leq\sqrt[3]x<y+1$. Get rid of the cube roots by cubing both sides of the inequalities.

Comment: This looks correct. (Another way to handle "less than or equal" would be as "not greater".)